# C# custom table paging issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made an asp.net webapplication which displays data from my MySQL database in a html table, I made it so that only 20 rows can be seen at once, and on a button_click event the next 20 rows could be seen, and so on. However, after the 6th click, it displays 40 rows instead and the button can't be clicked anymore.

the HTML

```
<div>
    <table id="datagrid" runat="server">
    </table>
    <asp:Button OnClick="Unnamed_Click" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

The C# code [Final - working, incase anyone would need it]

```
int minrows = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayData();
    }
    private void DisplayData()
    {
        if (ViewState["minrows"] != null)
        {
            minrows = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["minrows"]);
        }
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=apollo;user=root;password=mysqltest");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Klantnr, Naam, Straat FROM tblklanten LIMIT "+minrows+", 20", conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell td1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell td2 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell td3 = new HtmlTableCell();
            datagrid.Controls.Add(tr);
            td1.InnerText = Reader["Klantnr"].ToString();
            td2.InnerText = Reader["Naam"].ToString();
            td3.InnerText = Reader["Straat"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(td1);
            tr.Controls.Add(td2);
            tr.Controls.Add(td3);
        }
        Reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minrows += 20;
        ViewState["minrows"] = minrows;
        datagrid.Controls.Clear();
        DisplayData();
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue here ?

Comment: after the 6th click, it displays 40 rows instead and the button can't be clicked anymore.

Comment: instead of that, what needs to happen ?

Comment: next 20 rows should be displayed everytime the button is clicked, not 40.

Comment: `count<maxrows` - what is the point of this?

Comment: Did you debug the code and check values of minRows and maxRows on 6th click. What query is being executed on db?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel here?  There's already several data grid controls in .NET with paging.

Comment: @Igor Good question, I've been asking this myself as well, but it doesn't work at all if I remove it.

Comment: @Seano666 I don't like datagrids

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp - you are using `MySQL.LIMIT` clause incorrectly

Comment: @Igor thank you, you are a life saver, Apparently I got the information on the LIMIT clause from a website that wasn't trustworthy. It works now.

Comment: @user6875529 Glad I could help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MySQL.LIMIT` clause incorrectly

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

```
"... LIMIT " + minrows + ", " + (maxrows - minrows)
```